# Terraform experiment release `module_variable_optional_attrs`: variable with nested optional list object attribute

Tags: terraform

**Background:**

I'm creating a Terraform IAM role module that has a variable for defining policy statements. As you can see below, the variable uses optional attribute expression (see => 0.14.0 version releases for more info: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/releases).

```
variable "statements" {
  description = "IAM policy statements for role permissions" 
  type = list(object({
    effect = string
    resources = list(string)
    actions = list(string)
    conditions = optional(list(map(object({
      test = string
      variable = string
      values = list(string)
    }))))
  }))
  default = []
}
```

Terraform version: 0.14.3

Terraform block configuration:

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.14.0"
  experiments = [module_variable_optional_attrs]
  required_providers {
    aws = ">= 3.22"
  }
}
```

**Problem:**

Within the module's locals block, I want to define an empty list default for the `conditions` attribute. So far I've tried:

1.

```
statements = length(var.statements) > 0 ? [for statement in var.statements: defaults(statement.conditions, [])] : []
```

error:

```
Invalid value for "defaults" parameter: the default value for a collection of
an object type must itself be an object type, not tuple.
```

2. 

```
statements = length(var.statements) > 0 ? [for statement in var.statements: defaults(statement.conditions, [{}])] : []
```

error:

```
Invalid value for "defaults" parameter: the default value for a collection of
an object type must itself be an object type, not tuple.
```

For the #1 and #2 attempts, the default value type for the statement conditions attribute is a list but the errors outputs that the default type should be an object.

3.

```
statements = length(var.statements) > 0 ? [for statement in var.statements: defaults(statement, {conditions = []})] : []
```

error:

```
Invalid value for "defaults" parameter: .conditions: the default value for a
collection of an object type must itself be an object type, not tuple.
```

Comment: Typically what you want to do here is create a separate `local` for the policies with the design pattern described here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/flatten.html#flattening-nested-structures-for-for_each. This would also allow you to easily assign an empty list as the default since it would populate with an empty return from the iterator.